# implement clusterkraf in my app

Tags: android

I have imported clusterkraf into my app with no errors but how do I cluster(code) it.There is no info or step by step tutorial on the same.I really like the library and would like to implement the same.I  appreciate any help in adding few marks with custom icon on the map.Please help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: download sample here http://www.appszoom.com/android_applications/libraries_and_demo/clusterkraf-sample_gctwj_download.html and see https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/tree/master/sample/src/com/twotoasters/clusterkraf/sample